# Database are not visible to users who has access in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-3.0

We are using Robo 3t tool to interact with Mongodb. We could see the user has read access on 2 databases but when the user is connected to MongoInstance that databases are not visible to the users.

User has same permissions in other environments can able to see the databases.

Really appreciate help on this

Comment: What is the MOngoDB version(x,y,z)? Are you sure using the MongoDB version 3.0?

Comment: Can you update the reports after executing the query such as db.getUsers();

Comment: Did you try with MongoDB Compass tool?

Answer (score 0):

> We are using Robo 3t tool to interact with Mongodb. We could see the
>   user has read access on 2 databases but when the user is connected to
>   MongoInstance that databases are not visible to the users.

May be you have Robo 3t tool related issues (Such as certificate etc.), without log files can't exactly tell to that. But I would like to say that other than Robo 3t tool, you can use [MongoDB GUIs Tools](https://scalegrid.io/blog/which-is-the-best-mongodb-gui/) such as MongoDB Compass.

MongoDB Compass, MongoDB’s own GUI tool, supports the latest MongoDB versions and is available on Linux, Mac, or Windows. Introduced in MongoDB 3.2, Compass was developed to provide all the power of the mongo shell through an easy GUI tool. They always keep the free community version good enough to use MongoDB effectively, and you can expect them to improve this tool to continue enhancing its usability.

> User has same permissions in other environments can able to see the
>   databases.

Yes

For further your ref [here](https://dzone.com/articles/which-is-the-best-mongodb-gui-2019-update)